# disable realtime product indexing magento Enterprise

Tags: magento

We use Magento Enterprise v1.12. It occurs to me that product saving for us is taking really long (~12 seconds) so I'm investigating that. As we edit a lot of products (we have full-time content editors) it is important that editing is flexible and fast.

We use a lot of catalog rules and I noticed updating those for a saving product took ~7 seconds (of the ~12). I'm trying to have this disabled now as they will be updated at night anyway.

What occurs to me now is the following code in the catalog/product::_afterSave method:

```
        Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->processEntityAction(
        $this, self::ENTITY, Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_SAVE
    );
```

This code takes ~3-4 seconds and is unaffected by the current indexing mode (e.g. setting all indices to manual). Why is this? I would rather have 3-4 seconds faster saving and having the data reindexed over night. Does this code do anything important that should happen immediately? Is there a reason it is still indexing despite having my indices on manual (catalog_product_flat and catalog_url I would guess mostly).

Hope anyone has some insight. Would be cool to reduce product saving to ~2 seconds max :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the indexing mode to "Manual Update" from "Update on Save" in the index management?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that doesn't help the least oddly.